# Create Project Server Application Proxy on Front-end server (Project Server 2016)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, project-server

I am unable to create 'Project Server Application Proxy' on Front-end server.
It shows the error: **The topology service is not  running in the farm**. I found out that the reason for it is, "Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service" is disabled because it is a front-end server.

Comment: are you able to create the Service Application? how many server in the farm?

Comment: Service Application is already there. There are 4 servers in the farm.

Comment: U are trying to start project service instance on wfe, right?

Comment: Yes, can you help me with that?

Comment: could you please share the complete error? screenshot / event log.

Comment: You may please find the complete discussion on this link, here I have mentioned the whole scenario: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/244325/error-service-application-not-found/244327?noredirect=1#comment261219_244327

Comment: Also,please let me know soon if it is anyhow possible to start Project Server Service Application Proxy on server with Front-end role. That's the main requirement?

Comment: have to try to run the psconfig wizard on the problematic server? try this one PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force

Comment: Is it possible to create Project Server Service Application Proxy on Front-end server role?

Comment: Yes, it is supported on the Front-end server role

Comment: How to do that? I am not getting that information anywhere. The other question is bout that only.